# Am I affected by a security hole in OAuth that this article mentions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have created an MVC site with the MVC 5.1 template in Visual Studio 2013. I used the authentication built into the template. I did NOT use the SPA template. Users can log in either with a local account or via OAuth with Google, and eventually, other sites. The local account does not use OAuth.

I saw this article http://technotes.iangreenleaf.com/posts/closing-a-nasty-security-hole-in-oauth.html and cannot determine if I am affected by the issue at hand.

Can someone please teach me how to determine if I am affected by it?